# extracting specific value from pyspark streaming rdd

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, rdd

I have json rdd in that i have printed using pprint as shown below

```
[u'{']
[u'"hash" ', u' "0000000000000000059134ebb840559241e8e2799f3ebdff56723efecfd6567a",']
[u'"confirmations" ', u' 969,']
[u'"size" ', u' 52543,']
[u'"height" ', u' 395545,']
[u'"version" ', u' 4,']
[u'"merkleroot" ', u' "8cf3eea32f692e5ebc9c25bb912ab3aff43c02761609d52cdd48afc5a05918fb",']
[u'"tx" ', u' [']
[u'"b3df3d5fedadd07a46753af556c336c41e038a9aec7ddd9921ad249828fd6d66",']
[u'"4ada431255d104c1c76ef56bdef4186ea89793223133e535383ff39d5a322910",']
```

I want to extract the 2nd last value `[u'"b3df3d5fedadd07a46753af556c336c41e038a9aec7ddd9921ad249828fd6d66",']`

How to get this value when indexing does not work. The code is below

```
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
import json

# Create a local StreamingContext with two working thread and batch interval of 1 second
sc = SparkContext("local[2]", "txcount")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)
dump_rdd = lines.map(lambda x: json.dumps(x))
load_rdd = dump_rdd.map(lambda x: json.loads(x))
tx = load_rdd.map(lambda x: x.split(":"))
tx.pprint()
```

Comment: Simply don't try. You shouldn't pass multiline inputs this way.

Comment: @zero323 Lets say, If this was single line, how would you extract it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socketTextStream` is not designed to handle multiline records. While it is not impossible to reassemble complete records I doubt it is worth the effort. If you want to use `socketTextStream` for simplicity just encode (for example using Base64 encoding) or clean your data upstream before passing to Spark.

Comment: @zeros323. I asked the question in my earlier comment about "what if it is single line json?"

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions and help